# React Navigation: How to trigger navigation.push() in bottom tab navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Here is what I am trying to do in my app with react navigation:

1. There is a default bottom tab navigator.
2. The app will listen to changes in the data.
3. If there is a change in the data for any of the screens in the bottom tab navigator, trigger navigation.push() to refresh the component.

What I observed is that the default behavior of the bottom tab navigator is navigation.navigate()...i.e. unless I reload the app, the screens do not refresh themselves.

In short, how do I trigger navigation.push() in the tab navigator? e.g. in the sample code below, how do I set the navigation behavior?

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
//How do I trigger navigation.push() when each of the bottom tab is pressed?
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
       <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
       </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pulled the following example from my code which solved the issue for me;

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/routers';

  onPress={() => {
  const pushAction = 
  StackActions.push('ProfileAnimal', { animal_id: item.id });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(pushAction);
  this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileAnimal', {animal_id: item.id});
 };
```